# Unity resolving cyclic dependency

Tags: c#, unity-container

While learning Unity (DI framework in `C#`) I came across a situation where one class has a setter injection of `ClassB`

```
class ClassA : IClassA
{
    [Dependency]
    public IClassB ClassB
    {
        get { return _classB; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            _classB = value;
        }
    }
```

and the other has a constructor injection of the `ClassA`

```
class ClassB : IClassB
{
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public ClassB(IClassA classA)
    {
        _classA = classA;
    }
}
```

I am not able to resolve both the classes correctly within the container.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IClassB, ClassB>();
container.RegisterType<IClassA, ClassA>();
IClassA classA = new ClassA();
var instance = container.Resolve<ClassA>();
instance.DoSomethingFromClassB();

log.Info("Constructor Injection");
var instanceB = container.Resolve<ClassB>();
instanceB.DoSomethingFromClassA();
```

This gives me a stack overflow exception

I tried different ordering of resolving this but it doesn't seem to work.

I this doable or am I just wasting my time.

What is exactly happening here ?

Answer (score 22):

I agree with @Haney that **this is a code smell**, but it is technically possible...

Just change one of the referenced types to be resolved via `Lazy<T>`.  Then it does not actually resolve that type until it is used which will break out of the infinite recursion loop.

i.e.

```
class ClassB : IClassB
{
...
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public ClassB(Lazy<IClassA> classA)
    {
        _classA = classA;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. We were refactoring to use constructor injection, which brought to light some circular dependencies. We ended up using this as an interim solution so that we could check in what we had and clean up the circular dependencies as a separate task.

Comment: As a word of encouragement for those who get here. I would say, yes sometimes it is a code smell, but sometimes its the result of a codebase feeling growing pains. As long as you try to steer clear of property injection I wouldn't sweat it too much. Good luck out there!

Comment: how to we get the instantiated object

Answer (score 21):

The way that DI frameworks like Unity work is, when you call them to instantiate a class, they recursively instantiate all classes being passed into the constructor (or set by property) of that class. Those classes follow the same function, and so you can see how you've created an infinite loop of recursion. How does Unity construct A when it needs B and B when it needs A? Neither can ever be constructed.

You can't resolve co-dependent classes in most DI frameworks. **This is a bad design pattern AKA a code smell.** In the classical sense, if `ClassA` needs to know about `ClassB`, and `ClassB` in return needs to know about `ClassA`, then the reality is that they share concerns and should be combined into a single class `ClassC`. You gain nothing by having them in 2 separate classes since there is no separation of concerns in this case.

DI such as Unity is used to promote the pattern of **Inversion of Control**, which works only when classes have a one-way dependency (don't need to know about each other).

Comment: Yes, you could have C resolve A and B. This is a common pattern as well - having a "container" or "composer" that holds the two related classes. Don't get too hung up on the buzzwords/jargon though. ;)