# your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

this is a piece of  my code in xamarin android , When Vs 2017 want to execute the line "await Task.Delay(200);" , the error mentioned in title will apear, please tell me if anybody know about that

```
private async void _btnanswer2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Ans == 2)
        {
            _btnanswer2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#006400"));
            mScore = mScore + 1;
            _txtscore.Text = "امتیاز: " + mScore.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            _btnanswer2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
        await Task.Delay(200); //Error after Execute this line
     _btnanswer2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("0091EA"));
        bandeira++;
        RefreshQue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634776/your-app-has-entered-a-break-state-but-there-is-no-code-to-show-because-all-thr), do like @atik sarker has said.

Or you can add `try-catch` to get the error message.

---

In your code, this line

`btnanswer2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("0091EA"));`

It will throw `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color`

So you need add `#`, please replace it with `btnanswer2.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#0091EA"));`