# Xamarin.Android crash after upgrading to Xamarin.Forms 4.2

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 4.2.  For Android, it crashed immediately after launch.

The error message is 
Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

After tracing through the code, the app has launched and there is no code left to execute.  Then, it crashed.

Comment: Make sure that the version of xamarin.forms in your android project is also up-to-date .You can delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in your share project and android project,then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47901393/1663657) to get more information about error.

Comment: I followed the instruction given by Renan.  Here is my the relevant error message: `I/MonoDroid(13288): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
I/MonoDroid(13288): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I/MonoDroid(13288):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.op_Implicit (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform canvas) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:491`

Comment: The same code works flawlessly in Xamarin.Forms 4.1.  Is there any major changes in Android.AppCompat?

Comment: It seems an existing issue , you can focus on it https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7301.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lucas.  As suggested, in SplashActivity.cs, change the class declaration to
`public class SplashActivity : global::Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Had the same issue with a project, and was able to solved by changing from FormsAppCompatActivity to global::Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity too