# MVP dependency injection caused infinite loop

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container, stack-overflow

I'm working with `WPF`, `MVP` and `Unity Framework` for `dependency injection`.

---

When I resolve `IniciarSesionView`, it comes to an infinite loop of creation of `IniciarSesionView` and `IniciarSesionPresentador`.

#### App.cs

```
Current.MainWindow = IoCFactory.Instance.CurrentContainer.Resolve<Vistas.IniciarSesionView>();
```

#### Code behind

```
public partial class IniciarSesionView : Window, IIniciarSesion
{
    private IniciarSesionPresentador _presentador;

    public IniciarSesionView(IniciarSesionPresentador presentador)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presentador = presentador;
    }
}


public class IniciarSesionPresentador
{
    private readonly IIniciarSesion _view;

    public IniciarSesionPresentador(IIniciarSesion view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a circular dependency here. How do you suppose it to work? Use `Lazy<T>` to avoid instance creation on resolving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity resolving cyclic dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669677/unity-resolving-cyclic-dependency)

Comment: Dependency cycles are often caused by either Interface Segregation Principle or Single Responsibility Principle violations. Try to split `IIIniciarSesion` into multiple smaller interfaces and implementations in such way that the cycle disappears.